# I am not getting FCM message probably FirebaseMessagingService is not running

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM for notification. Due to some issue, i am not getting notification when i am sending using FCM Cloud console.

```
   <service android:name=".MyInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".MyMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

This is my both classes.

```
    public class MyInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyInstanceIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
       String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        System.out.println("Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        // Util.getInstance().saveDeviceID(UniversalImageLoaderConfigurationApplication.getContext(), refreshedToken);
        // sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    }

    public class MyMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyMessagingService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Displaying data in log
        //It is optional
        // if(LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
//        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        int id = Integer.parseInt(data.get("id"));
        if (id == (Constants.NOTI_NOTIFCATION)) {
            String title = data.get("title");
            String body = data.get("body");
            sendNotification(id, title, body, "");
        } else {
            sendNotification(1, "", "", "");
        }

    }

     }
```

I noted that **public void onTokenRefresh()** never called. So i used it

> String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

in my MainActivity and i am getting tokenID. probably FirebaseInstanceIdService and FirebaseMessagingService is not running. below is my gradle

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

and i also used

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is my root level gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
//    google()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    jcenter()
   // mavenCentral()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services     plugin

    }

}

allprojects {
repositories {
   // google()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
}
```

Comment: onTokenRefresh()  is called only once when the app is installed first time or when reinstalled. Uninstall the app and put a log in onTokenRefresh()  and install it again and check in the logcat.

Comment: @JineshMalavia yes. but it never called. something issue in FirebaseInstanceIdService and FirebaseMessagingService. i think  service is not running. can we track that it is running?

Comment: As you mentioned that you are not receiving notifications the service is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actions are reversed for your service declarations.  Change to this:

```
   <service android:name=".MyInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".MyMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

See the [example in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest).